# How to execute a command when clicking a button (discord.net)?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I want to execute my Task "test1", when the Button "Spieler moven" is clicked. How do i do that? Currently you write !test1 and than it executes.
So a player clicks the button "Spieler moven" and the task "test1" gets executed.

```
[Command("spawner")]
        public async Task Spawn()
        {
            var builder = new ComponentBuilder()
                .WithButton("Spieler moven", "1", ButtonStyle.Success);
            

        await ReplyAsync("Welche Option willst du ausführen?", components: builder.Build());

        

    }

 public async Task Test1()
    {
        
        var user = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
        

        var Queuelist = Context.Guild.GetVoiceChannel(936628853340778506).Users; //Checke ob jemand in der Warteschlange ist
        bool Queue = false; //Standardmäßig Niemand in der Queue
        foreach (var u in Queuelist)
        {
            Queue = true; 
        }
        if (Queue == true)
        {
            

               var VoiceUsers = Context.Guild.GetVoiceChannel(936628853340778507).Users; // Checke ob Support 1 besetzt ist
            bool sup1 = false;
            foreach (var u in VoiceUsers)
            {
            bool supporter = u.Equals(Context.User); // Checke ob der Supporter selbst in Support 1 ist
                if (supporter == false)
                    sup1 = true;
               
            }

            if (sup1 == false)
            {
                await user.ModifyAsync(x => { x.ChannelId = 936628853340778507; }); //Move zu Support 1
            }
            else
            {
                await user.ModifyAsync(x => { x.ChannelId = 936628853340778508; }); //Support 1 ist voll, move zu Support 2
            }


        } else
            await ReplyAsync("" + Context.Message.Author.Mention + ", es befindet sich niemand bei Tränix :c");


          
    }
```

Thanks beforehand

Comment: https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_basics/message-components/responding-to-buttons.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the InteractionCreated Event and then trigger your Task from there on.

I'm handling my buttons this way, but there might be an easier solution today as this code was made about 3 months ago.

```cs
        public HandlingService(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            _client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();

            _client.InteractionCreated += HandleInteractionCreated;
        }
```

```cs
        private async Task HandleInteractionCreated(SocketInteraction interaction)
        {
            switch (interaction.Type)
            {
                case InteractionType.ApplicationCommand:
                    //Handle SlashCommands
                    break;
                case InteractionType.ApplicationCommandAutocomplete:
                    //Handle Autocomplete
                    break;
                case InteractionType.MessageComponent:
                    MessageComponentHandlingService.MessageComponentHandler(interaction)
                    break;
                default: // We dont support it
                    Console.WriteLine("Unsupported interaction type: " + interaction.Type);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

```cs
    class MessageComponentHandlingService
    {
        public static async Task MessageComponentHandler(SocketInteraction interaction)
        {
             var parsedArg = (SocketMessageComponent)interaction;
             switch (parsedArg.Data.CustomId)
             {
                  case "Spieler moven": //maybe also "spieler moven" Here you have to insert the costom ID of the button
                  await Test1()
                      break;
             }
        }
    }
```